# How to remove duplicate values in an array while printing the other values in the duplicated element

Tags: php, arrays

I have an output of a query (passed from a controller to a view) that is converted into a JSON array as shown below.

```
array (size=14)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'student_id' => string '8660' (length=4)
      'session_count' => int 6
      'type' => string 'lecture' (length=7)
      'group' => null
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'student_id' => string '8660' (length=4)
      'session_count' => int 5
      'type' => string 'practical' (length=9)
      'group' => string 'A' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      'student_id' => string '8661' (length=4)
      'session_count' => int 7
      'type' => string 'lecture' (length=7)
      'group' => null
  3 => 
    array (size=4)
      'student_id' => string '8661' (length=4)
      'session_count' => int 3
      'type' => string 'practical' (length=9)
      'group' => string 'B' (length=1)
  4 => 
    array (size=4)
      'student_id' => string '8662' (length=4)
      'session_count' => int 4
      'type' => string 'lecture' (length=7)
      'group' => null
```

I want to print Student_id Session Count(Lectures) Session Count(Practical) in a table (such that each student number appears only in one row along with the relevant Lectures and Practical session counts). 
I searched extensively for a solution. All the solution available in this forum to remove duplicates also removes an entire array element thereby deleting lecture/practical and session count values included in it. My @foreach loop prints with duplicates.

How to print this in the above format while printing unique student_ids along with relevant Session Count(Lectures) Session Count(Practical) in a table. I am using Laravel 4.2.

Answer (score 1):

You have to first create one empty array outside of for-each loop then first check whether student_id exist in a created array or not, If not then push student_id in an array, If not then continue loop without printing details.